# angula2-jwt AuthHttp issue

Tags: angular6, angular2-jwt

am using angular v6 when i try to use AuthHttp from angular2-jwt in my service constructor the page wont do any request or render.
I have added AUTH_PROVIDERS to the providers, but I have no error at the same time.

```
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';


@Injectable()

export class VehicleService {

  private readonly vehiclesEndPoint = "/api/vehicle/";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authHttp: AuthHttp) { }
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to import the HttpClientModule as well.